# Extend GCKUICastContainerViewController below the Home Indicator

Tags: google-cast, iphone-x

I'm integrating GoogleCast to my app. Its root view controller is a `UITabBarController`, with a custom white tab bar.

After I wrapped it with a `GCKUICastContainerViewController`, the Home Indicator background area became black (and the indicator is white).

How can I make this Container VC extend its child VC (my tab bar controller) below the home indicator?

Note: There is an ugly workaround that I tried, which is to set `castContainerVC.view.backgroundColor = .white`. This would work if the tab bar was always visible, but some parts of my navigation stack may choose to hide it. When it happens, I'd end with a white Home Indicator area, but whatever color the presented view controller has above the indicator.

Comment: You can file a feature request: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:190205%20status:open&s=modified_time:desc

Answer (score 0):

```
    extension GCKUICastContainerViewController {

        open override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
            super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

            if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow, miniMediaControlsViewController?.view.bounds.height ?? 0 == 0 {
                contentViewController?.view.frame = window.frame
        
            } else {
                contentViewController?.view.frame = (view.subviews.first! as UIView).frame
            }
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it appears Google wants us to have the `GCKUICastContainerViewController` as the root view controller. And it looks like it has some layout issue when there is safe area inset at the bottom of the display.

I solved this by changing the view's frame manually in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. You can do it with an extension like this

```
extension GCKUICastContainerViewController {

    open override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
            contentViewController?.view.frame = window.frame
        }
    }
}
```

This way you will get rid of the space at the bottom of the screen. Works for me.

Comment: That solves the initial layout, but now when the mini player appears, the app content does not get resized properly.